# Measurement of Surface Tension of a Liquid by Capillary Rise Method

Tags: experimental-physics, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action, liquid-state

The surface tension at the point of contact for water is inwards (as written in my book) so that would mean it vertical component is downwards but why is that vertical component considered upwards?
I found this on google even here I don't understand why isn't the vertical component of $T$ cancelling out vertical component of $R$. What happens to $T\cos{x}$?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Surface tension and capillary rise](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207925/)

Comment: Nope... They dont talk about the forces, im having trouble with the forces

Answer (score 1):

Each water molecule clings to the surface, and to surrounding water molecules, somewhat like a climber clinging to a rock (and to other climbers if there is a whole heap of climbers). The weight of the climber's body (and of anything else dangling below him on a rope) is balanced by the force between his hand and the rock face. It is similar with the water molecules and the capillary tube.

Answer (score 1):

A glass tube of very small diameter is called capillary

If we dip the capillary tube in water, due to the concave surface, pressure just below the surface becomes $P-\frac{2T}{r}$,

$T$ - surface tension of the liquid.
$r$ - radius of curvature of the water surface.

while on the other points at the same horizontal level, pressure is $P$. ***Due to this less pressure, water level in the tube rises up, till pressure becomes equal at the same horizontal level (i.e. at points A and B)***

Let $h$ be the rise in height in the capillary tube.

$P - \frac{2T}{r} + dgh = P$

$h = \frac{2T}{dgr}$

$d$ - density of the liquid.

Although we have derived it for water, it works for other liquids too which forms a conacve meniscus.
In case of liquids having convex meniscus it becomes $P + \frac{2T}{R}$ instead of $P - \frac{2T}{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the normal force is always considered perpendicular to surface, so that any object in this case , water molecules doesn't enter the surface of capillary tube i.e the horizontal component force due to surface tension $T$ which is $2 \pi RT sin \theta$ gets cancelled by opposite normal force which is acting perpendicular to surface of capillary in horizontal direction, so there is only vertical component of surface tension  which is $2 \pi R T \cos \theta$ which is acting and is getting balanced by whole weight of liquid column , so conclusion is normal force is perpendicular to surface of capillary tube there is no component of it in vertical direction.

Comment: Isnt 2πrTcosx acting downwards then? The surface tension is acting inwards right? So its vertical component should be downwards

Comment: @Meow how can 2$\pi rT\cos x$ act downwards if the weight of whole column is to be balanced, the  force vector  due to surface tension $2\pi r T $ is having 2 components along vertical upward direction($2\pi r \cos x$) and along horizontal direction towards surface of capillary ($2\pi r \sin x$) where $x$ is contact angle

Comment: @Meow whole surface tension force not only act towards right but  there is vertical component as well , its direction depends on contact angle, usually a concave surface is formed , and forces due to surface tension is along the boundary of liquid towards outside

Comment: Thats the part i didnt understand. why is the vertical component of the surface tension upwards? Its written in my book that the surface tension at the point of contact for water is inwards so if thats inwards its vertical component would be downwards. Is there a mistake in my book?

Comment: Yes i understood that the vertical component has to be upwards to balance the weight but it doesnt make sense why would it be upwards if the surface tension is acting inwards

Comment: For the surface tension acting towards the outside in my book it was written for mercury

Comment: @Meow looks like you need to update your question now ,your original question is residing in this comment section, but still shortly saying the molecules of liquid at boundary are held by solid-liquid interaction of tube which is stronger than liquid-liquid, so now this liquid molecules at boundary shall exert some force on molecules below in chain which pulls whole column.